# Connecting Lotus Notes to Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, lotus-notes

**Is there a way to connect Lotus Notes to Thunderbird?**

My company uses Lotus Notes as one of the email clients. I'd prefer using Thunderbird because it's free and also because I find it more intuitive. I looked online and on forums, but didn't manage finding a way to connect Lotus Notes to Thunderbird.

**Want on Thunderbird:**

1. to be able to send and receive emails
2. receive calender events
3. absolutely very little need to open Lotus Notes

Is this even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notes [supports](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_admin.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/3a89e0cc5329e70485256c1d003963b4?OpenDocument) IMAP service.

Thunderbird is an IMAP client.

So yes it is possible. Contact your Notes admin for details of the IMAP service (hostname, port, login credentials).

Comment: thanks for your answer. Sorry, I didn't get to verify your answer by establishing a connection between Notes 6.5 and Thunderbird. Thankfully, my company decided to upgrade my Notes to version 8! Will get back to this issue if I'm not satisfied by Notes 8 either...